# .remove() does not remove element from the dom

Tags: jquery

I want to remove an element from the dom using its id

**HTML**

```
<div id="no-js">
     Sorry for the inconvenience<br/>
     Your browser does not support javascript or it must be  disabled.<br/>
     To access the features of our website<br/><br/>
     Enable your javascript or upgrade to the browser that supports javascript.
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
 var x = $("#no-js"); 
 console.log(x.html());
 x.remove(); // does not remove the element from dom why?
 console.log(x.html()); // it displays html content inside it
 console.log(x.length); // results 1 
 x.empty(); // removes the child elements, working as expected
 console.log(x.html()); // html content is empty
 console.log(x.length); // length is 1
```

`.remove()` does not seem to work as expected ?
This is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/QGsza/14/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.remove()` removes the element from the dom, but still the variable `x` holds a reference to it that is the reason for `x.length` to return 1

If you test again `console.log($("#no-js").length)` it will give 0 as it triggers a new dom search and the element is already removed

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/36SyH/)

Answer (score 0):

Do like that i have tried in you fiddle and it is working

```
var x = $("#no-js").html();
x.remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your selector is wrong, change to `$("#no_js")`. For more information consult the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)